# Using CSS Flip effects, but after submit i want to disable pageload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
        <input type="text" name="pemail" id="rec_email" placeholder="Emailadres" class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="form-actions">
    <span class="pull-left"><a href="#" class="flip-link grey" id="to-login">&lt; Terug naar login</a></span>
    <span class="pull-right"><input type="submit" id="psubmit" name="psubmit" class="btn btn-inverse" value="Bevestig" /></span>
</div>
```

As you can see, in the HTML, name and id are psubmit. and input field emails name is pemail and id= rec_email.

Errors shown by this code:

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['pemail']) === false || empty($_POST['pemail']) === true) {
        echo 'Forgot pass? typ your email';
    }

    if (isset($_GET['success']) === true && empty($_GET['success']) === true) {
        echo '<font color="green">Done! check email.</font>';               
    }
    else {
        if(isset($_POST['pemail']) === true && empty($_POST['pemail']) === false) {
            if($users->email_exists($_POST['pemail']) === true) {
                $users->confirm_recover($_POST['pemail']);

                header('Location:confirm-recover.php?success');
                exit();
            }
            else {
                echo '<font color="red">Email does not exist .</font>';
            }
        } 
    }

?>
```

I have a loginform, that when I click on password lost, the loginbox pulls himself to the right by effects, so it isnt an other page where the user asking for password. Thanks to effecs of CSS/js

Errors and the code are working perfect, but when I click on PSUBMIT, when the user is asking his email, it reloads the page and stars at the login form which aint a good thing because the errors are shown in the lost password field, when clicked Password lost? and like I said it isnt another link its the same page thats why it loads at the start of the index.php (the login form) So the user needs to click again on the password lost effect to see the error.

I thought it would be better when I click on PSUBMIT that the page doesnt RELOADS but give me the error or does the job anyway.

I added this JS

```
<script>
    $("#psubmit").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }        
</script>
```

Now the page isn't loading, but it aint giving me any errors or doesn't send the code to the user.

Can you guys help me?

Comment: For the submit button not to submit, add `onclick="return false;"`. In that way, the Javascript of the onclick is run, and as it returns false, then the submit will not be run. Actually, you probably want the `onclick` to check something, like if the `pemail` is filled in or not, then return true (to submit) or false (to cancel).

Comment: Please can you specify what you mean, I didn't understand that, i added onclick="return false;" in the submit, and deleted the JS code, now it does not reload page either but also no errors.

Comment: anyone please? I am stuck here hehe ^^